# How do I make the input values accessible while keeping the toggle functionality?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a dynamic signup screen, where the customer first gets a basic view presented (code up until the

)

After clicking on this basic field a more detailed registry screen appears (all below)

```
<div class="user__action user__signup">
                <b>Sign up</b>
                
                <div class="user__management" id="signup">
                        <div class="form_template" class="user__action">
                            <form id="user__registform">
                                <p>Please enter your preferred credentials!</p>
                                <input type="text" id="regist_name" placeholder="Please enter your nickname!" required="required" form="user__registform">
                                <input type="email" id="regist_mail" placeholder="Please enter a valid e-mail!" required="required" form="user__registform">
                                <input type="password" id="regist_pw" placeholder="Please enter a password!" minglength="9" maxlength="16" required="required" form="user__registform">
                                <input type="password" id="regist_pw--conf" placeholder="Please confirm your password!" minglength="9" maxlength="16" required="required" form="user__registform">
                                <input form="user__registform" type="submit" value="Register" class="user__regist--submit">
                            </form>
                        </div>
                 </div>
```

While I managed fairly easy to listen to the click event and toggle back and forth the signup area, the same function makes the input fields inaccessible, as on a further click they disappear. Javascript function looks like this:

```
let signupArea = $('.user__signup);
let sigunpInv = false;

signupArea.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    signupInv ? ($('#signup').css('display', 'none')) : ($('#signup').css('display', 'block'));
    signupInv = !signupInv;

});
```

I tried two solutions, first adding an e.stopPropagation(), but this seemed to achieve nothing, as the toggling back and forth still worked, second, I added a guard clause with (if e.target !== this) {return}; but this had the unintended consequence, that I was unable to open toggle the signup.

Could somebody help, how I can both access the input fields (giving them values through the UI) and keep my toggle functionality?

Thank you a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that writing my problem I just came to a semi-acceptable solution.

I modified my JS code as follows, by adding a second condition to the if-else in the guard clause:

```
    signupArea.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        if (signupInv === true && e.target !== this) return;
    
        signupInv ? ($('#signup').css('display', 'none')) : ($('#signup').css('display', 'block'));
        signupInv = !signupInv;

});
```

Now the guard clause is only triggered, if the signup button has been triggered once, and the whole signup field is visible. It solves my first problem, but I am still unable to submit the form, so any input is highly appreciated.